# ZF3 Zend\Math\Rand "This PHP environment doesn't support secure random number generation." PHP 5.6 with Mcrypt and openssl

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm using ZF3 and have just configured an application on a new server and I get the following error when generating CSRF tokens

```
This PHP environment doesn't support secure random number generation. Please consider upgrading to PHP 7
```

The server is running PHP 5.6.28 so I checked the ZF3 migration guide which states:

"This message should appear if your are using PHP versions less than 7 on Windows machines without one of the following extensions or libraries installed:

- Mcrypt
- libsodium
- CAPICOM
- OpenSSL"

The server has both Mcrypt and OpenSSL.  I'm also using the random_compact library as required.  Any idea what I'm missing?  Or is PHP 7 the only solution?  Thanks.

Comment: If you're using random_compat v2, it does **NOT** support OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

This caused by `Zend\Math\Rand::getBytes()` using `random_bytes()` function. This function was added to PHP in PHP 7.0

http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php

If you cannot upgrade your PHP Version, you can check this userland implementation for PHP 5.2 to 5.6

https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

Although this library has been examined by some security experts in the PHP community, there will always be a chance that we overlooked something. If you are using an unsupported version of PHP, please upgrade as soon as possible.